# How do you model resources in Rails that have no CRUD? How would you use the Attributes API to do that?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, ruby-on-rails-5

My specific use case is a set list of industries. Every account has an industry. It can only have one. I think the standard approach is to add a table, add a model, and use a foreign key `industry_id` on the `accounts` table.

But since industries isn't a CRUD resource, I wanted to use the Attributes API. I tried using an IndustryType, following the Rails docs, but this doesn't give me an id? How can I have an `attribute :industry` in conjunction with an `industry_id` column in the database?

I just found the API to be a little confusing, appreciate any help in understanding it better.

Comment: Can an account have more than one industry?

Comment: @hashrocket nope. Right now I've just got industry as a string, and a constant Account::INDUSTRIES that's an array of the possibilities for validation, but I don't think that's the best way to do it, just the laziest.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, what you're trying to do is create an association between an account and an industry. First, generate your industry model:

```
rails g model Industry
```

Then generate your account model:

```
rails g model Account industry:references
```

The `industry:references` will give you an industry_id column in the account table. You'll be able to call `account.industry` to get the account's industry, but not `industry.account`. If you want to be able to call `industry.account` and get the industry's account, you'll have to run another migration to add the account_id to the industry table:

```
rails g migration add_account_id_to_industry account:references
```

This will add the account_id column to your table. Now you can also call `industry.account` and receive the industry's account.

Neither one of these will give you CRUD capabilities. They will only create the models and the tables.